# using TinyXML Parsing XML Elements - Infinite loop

Tags: c++, xml, parsing, using, tinyxml

I want to read an xml file where several tests are found, but I always get the first one and it does not come out of the loop.
If I do an iteration well, but when I do the bubcle, I can not move on to the next test.

And if I use // pBodys = pRoot-> NextSiblingElement ("Test");
I miss an error in the 2 iteration,
(https://i.gyazo.com/9a108bf422299b66abfe91127668a63c.png)
 if I do not use it it stays in an infinite loop

(https://i.gyazo.com/133be25514a8a000fce87e2fc7cc52ad.png)

I can not move on.
Sorry for the google translation.
a greeting

```
    int main()
    {
        XMLDocument doc;
        doc.LoadFile("example.xml");
        XMLElement *pRoot, *pBodys, *pParms, *pParms2, *pProcess, *pApp, *pLineFormat, *pParm, *pParm2, *count;
        pRoot = doc.FirstChildElement("Tests");
        if (pRoot)
        {
            count = pRoot->FirstChildElement("count");
            std::cout << "cont=" << count->Attribute("cont") << std::endl;
            pBodys = pRoot->FirstChildElement("Test");
            //for (int i = 0; i < (int)count->Attribute("cont"); i++) {


            std::cout << "id=" << pBodys->Attribute("id") << std::endl;
            if (pBodys) {
                pParms = pBodys->FirstChildElement("Inputs");
                if (pParms)
                {
                    pParm = pParms->FirstChildElement("Input");
                    while (pParm) {

                        std::cout << "port=" << pParm->Attribute("port") << " ";
                        std::cout << "value=" << pParm->Attribute("value") << std::endl;


                        pParm = pParm->NextSiblingElement("Input");
                    }
                }
                pParms2 = pBodys->FirstChildElement("Outputs");
                if (pParms2)
                {
                    pParm2 = pParms2->FirstChildElement("Output");
                    while (pParm2) {

                        std::cout << "port=" << pParm2->Attribute("port") << " ";
                        std::cout << "value=" << pParm2->Attribute("value") << std::endl;


                        pParm2 = pParm2->NextSiblingElement("Output");
                    }
                }



            }

            //pBodys = pRoot->NextSiblingElement("Test");
        //}
    }

    return 0;
}

DOC example.xml 
<Tests>
    <count cont="2"></count>
    <Test id="test0">
        <Inputs>
            <Input port="A" value="1" />
            <Input port="B" value="4.56" />
            <Input port="C" value="7" />        
        </Inputs>
        <Outputs>
            <Output port="D" value="10" />      
        </Outputs>
    </Test>

    <Test id="test1">
        <Inputs>
            <Input port="K" value="3" />
            <Input port="L" value="9.56" /> 
        </Inputs>
        <Outputs>
            <Output port="P" value="6" />       
        </Outputs>
    </Test>
</Tests>
```

Comment: You should use TiXmlAttribute::QueryIntValue() as shown in this TinyXML [example](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/tutorial0.html)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that XMLElement.Attribute returns a `const char*` representing a C string, not an `int`. So this code

```
 (int)count->Attribute("cont");
```

is incorrect as you are casting a pointer to an integer (which typically results in a very large integer value, hence your apparent infinite loop).

What you need to do is **convert** the attribute to an `int` not cast it. One way to do that is to use the `atoi` function

```
int numTests = atoi(count->Attribute("cont"));
for (int i = 0; i < numTests; ++i) {
```

Note there is no error checking in this code (what if the attribute is missing or isn't in integral form?).

It's important to understand the difference between casting and converting one type to another. They don't always do the same thing, and just adding a cast to make a compiler error message go away is rarely the right thing to do.

Comment: That ruling actually had it fixed by directly entering the test number by hand, since I am allowed to do it.

The thing is when I perform
pBodys = pRoot-> NextSiblingElement ("Test");
to go to the next test, but in
std :: cout << "id =" << pBodys-> Attribute ("id") << std :: endl;
I missed the error, as if I could not pass the next test https://i.gyazo.com/8b79d5b34e61d97d6185ccb2d38efef7.png thanks for answer